# Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 405

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

While trying to extract data from Glassdoor, I got the following error.

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 405.

Here is the code:

```
rm(list=ls()) 

library("rvest")

htmlpage <- read_html("https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Reviews/Google-Reviews-E9079.htm")

forecasthtml <- html_nodes(htmlpage, ".summary")
```

SelectorGadget was used to select just the Headlines associated in each review and is given by `.summary` in the above code.

Is it because extracting data is not allowed or is there any fundamental mistake behind coding?

Comment: Provide elements you are trying to extract. Try using `RSelenium`